# Disallowing textbox editing if a ComboBox in the same Form is not filled (for each row individually)

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a Continuous Form with many different fields for each of the transaction number. I would like to restrict editing a TextBox (name TextBoxLawyer) if there is no value in a ComboBox from the same Row (for the same transaction).

I have the code below, but it locks the whole column from editing and is not looking for the value in the ComboBox from the corresponding row (from one record only). So it locks the entire TextBox in the Form and not just one record from a continuous form as I want it to.

```
If Me.Combo116.Value = "" Then

Me.TextBoxLawyer.Enabled = False

Else

Me.TextBoxLawyer.Enabled = True

End If
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do it and is it even possible?

Comment: There is only one textbox so programmatically setting properties affects all instances - every record will reflect same setting. Use Conditional Formatting and no VBA needed and textbox or combobox will be enabled/disabled independently for each record at same time.

Comment: Okay, I though it might be impossible. Thank you very much for clarifying this for me!

Comment: Your code will sort of work if it is placed in form Current and combobox AfterUpdate events. Just that as I said, every record will show the same setting which might be confusing to users (they would get used to it) but the setting would be correct for current record.

Comment: Yes, it does. Many thanks for the help! I will do it the way you first suggested through conditional formatting. Now trying to figure out, how to do it through expression builder. :)